# Attaching a file to an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

the documentation for attaching a file to an email references attaching a portfolio item. Is it possible to attach a file from the marketing cloud FTP? I would like to export data from a DE then attach it to an email campaign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course. The following AMPscript code will retrieve a file named `file.doc` from your Enhanced FTP Account import directory and attach it as a file using the filename `Attachment.doc`.

```
%%=AttachFile('FTP','file.doc','Attachment.doc')=%%
```

> Note: The `AttachFile()` AMPscript function is not enabled by default. This is an optional [paid] feature and is in addition to Super Messages. If you receive an error when previewing the email related to the feature not configured on your account, then you will need to contact your Account Manager to purchase a subscription for this feature.

Comment: Worth noting this is a paid feature that must be turned on through your account representative.

Comment: @Daniel, yes I called that out in my answer.

Comment: So you did. Not sure how I missed that!